# Bulk data retrieval from MySQL for Corba Iterator

Tags: mysql, iterator, corba

I have a client-server Corba application. For some calls, the Server provides an iterator object to Client as the returned data is huge. Current implementation - the server fetches all relevant data from (MySQL) Database and keeps in memory till client has finished retrieving all data (via the *getNext_n()* calls). Already, there is restriction on total number of iterators and it's lifetime (Evictor pattern). Now, the Server sometimes becomes Out of Memory if most open iterators have huge data.

1. What would be the best way to handle such scenario?
2. We can instead fetch data from DB in chunks (using Limit) instead of caching locally. But, if some other thread inserts/deletes rows in the table; the select would return inconsistent data. Using temporary table in turn means additional disk usage. Does MySQL provides any other mechanism to handle such scenario?

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to buffer anything from MySQL on Corba server.
You can execute a MySQL query on server and send iterator to client.
Then you fetch a row from MySQL query result set and send it to client right away. And repeat this for all rows in result set.

What you need to pay attention is to set a timeout for iterator. Client must finish one iteration in some time. This time should be less than time MySQL will allow to elapse between two row fetches from a result set.

Also, timeout is needed because if data in queried tables is changing during query it could fill MySQL UNDO log if result fetching takes too much time.